# What is this tense: sería / debía?

Tags: verbos, tiempos-verbales

> El Imperio Galáctico se derrumbaba. Era un imperio colosal que se
> extendía a través de millones de mundos, de un extremo a otro de la
> inmensa espiral doble que era la Vía Láctea. Su caída también
> **sería** colosal, y además prolongada, porque **debía** abarcar un enorme periodo de tiempo.
> Extracto de *Fundación e Imperio* de Isaac Asimov

What is the highlighted verb tense: **sería** / **debía**?
Please explain in detail from the beginning.

Comment: It would be a good idea to edit in to this what you think and what researches you have done.

Comment: Is that usage of "debia" an exact copy? (the translated text doesn't seem to be right)

Comment: That is a translation from English and not good for asking about Spanish grammar.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the book is translated and therefore not a good source for questions about Spanish.

Answer (score 1):

They are two different tenses.

**Sería** is in the *condicional* tense. In this sentence, it refers to an action that would happen in the future with respect to a time of reference in the past. It is similar to the conditional tense with "would" in English:

- It was a colossal Empire [...]. Its fall **would** also **be** colossal.

**Debía** is *pretérito imperfecto*. It describes an action that was ongoing in the past.

- Its fall would also be colossal, and also prolonged, because it had to span a long period of time.

It seems a strange choice of tense to me, as I would have used the *condicional* also here: "*debería* abarcar un enorme periodo de tiempo", or even better "*abarcaría* un enorme periodo de tiempo". The reason is that this is either a future action from the past perspective, or a hypothetical action. The *pretérito imperfecto* makes more sense if the action (the fall) was already happening at the point of time we are talking about, or if it is a direct consequence of another statement:

- Los enemigos del Imperio sabían que la victoria no llegaría pronto. La grandeza del Imperio significaba que su caída debía abarcar un enorme período de tiempo.